# Troubles using NONE when filtering an NSArray with an NSSet

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsset

I'm trying to filter an NSArray by excluding the elements that are in an NSSet. I'm doing something like this:

```
    NSMutableArray* a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
    NSSet* set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"2", nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE SELF IN %@", set];
    NSArray* b = [a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

However, this code throws an exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NOT` instead of `NONE` in the predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", set]
```

It is because the predicate is applied to each object (`SELF`) in the array, which is `NSString`. On the contrary, `None` should be applied on the `NSArray` of `NSSet`.

If you insist on using `NONE`. You may change `a` to

```
NSMutableArray* a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@[@"1"], @[@"2"], @[@"3"], nil];
```

so that the `SELF` becomes `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realized that :-). This answered my question. Thanks again